# React native: Component doesnt rerender when changing state with timer

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am new to react native and I am learning the basics about Hooks now. I created a very simple component called Timer which has three buttons - Start, Stop and Manual Change counter. The counter is a useState hook. 
Now the problem: when i change the counter by calling the changeCounterHandler function from button everything is correct. When I start the timer I can see it is "ticking" but the counter is never changed and the component is not rerendered. Why? :-)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';


const Timer = props => {

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const timerId = useRef();
    const timerDidMount = () => {
        console.log("timerDidMount");

    };

    const changeCounterHandler = () => {

        setCounter(counter+1);
        console.log(`counter: ${counter}`);
    };

    const startTimer = () => {
        timerId.current = setInterval(changeCounterHandler,1000);
    };
    const stopTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(timerId.current);
    };
return (

<View>
    <Text>{counter}</Text>
<Button title="Start timer" onPress={startTimer}></Button>
<Button title="Stop timer" onPress={stopTimer}></Button>
<Button title="change counter" onPress={changeCounterHandler}></Button>

</View>
)
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default Timer;
```

Thanks
Jan

Answer (score 0):

See if this works: use the function format to setCounter:
    setCounter(counter=>counter+1);

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks for the answer. I have just found it in the react docs as well. But I don't understand the reason. Can you please explain why it is needed to update it by function?

Comment: Because when u set the timer, it remember the initial value counter, it’s called closure, a confusing concept in JavaScript. The timer always access this initial value of counter. But the functional format of setState is to have the counter value in previous render as argument and return a new value based on the previous state value.